# Google Cloud Function 'node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding'

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

EDIT: I found the issue, when I copied the code I also duplicated the function. So I had cloud function "A" and "A Copy" and whenever I would pass information through the respective Pub/Sub, both functions are called and only one goes successfully through. I only did this because I thought having backup code somewhere would be safer and didn't expect it to make it not work.

So I've had a Google Cloud function running for the past 4 months.
Never any issues.
It uploads data I pass to it to FireStore.

I went to edit the code, but before I edited the code I made sure to backup the old code `**index.js**` and `**package.json**` just incase something broke.

Added a couple of new lines of code and of course the new code wasn't working so I reverted back to the old code.

However now the old code isn't working now and I'm getting:
Error: Cannot find module 'node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding'

so I commented everything and debugged as much as I could and found:

```
  db.collection('LiveExamples5').add
  ({
    Device: split[1],
    Index: split[5],
    Temperature: temp,
    Humidity: split[9],
    Raw: split[11],
    Resistance: split[13],
    VOC: split[15],
    VDD: split[17],
    Time: Timezz,
  });
```

This is the piece of code that uploads the passed data to Firestore causes the error.
It's strange since this is the old code it's now causing this error and not uploading anything to FireStore now.

I'm not even sure how to install modules into Google Cloud functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the dependency of node-pre-gyp to the package.json file.